# Method on Extended User Model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to write a method on my extended user model, "Person" (plural: People), that lists all the e-mail addresses so that later, users can find their friends.

Right now this is what my Person.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = function(Person) {
    Person.getPrefs = function(personId, cb) {
        Person.findById(personId,{ include: [{ relation: 'foodPrefs', scope: { include: { relation: 'food_pref_to_food_type' }}}]}, function(err, personFound) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }

            cb(null, personFound);
        });

    }

    Person.remoteMethod(
        'getPrefs', {
            http: {path: '/:personId/getPrefs', verb: 'get'},
            accepts: [{arg: 'personId', type: 'number'}],
            returns: {arg: 'type', type: 'object'},
            description: ['a person object']
        }
    );

};
```

The remote method above was generated automatically when building out the relational model in this experimental app. I've read the documentation on how to create a remote method, but I've not found it helpful enough to extrapolate what I need to do here.

Just for now, I want to create a method called findEmailAddresses and have it return all the e-mails for all users. I don't see any examples in the docs of how to return an array in a remote method much less or create more than one remote method in a single model. Here was my attempt, I'm just guessing at this, but it doesn't show up in the explorer as an option like the getPrefs method does:

```
module.exports = function(Person) {
    Person.getPrefs = function(personId, cb) {
        Person.findById(personId,{ include: [{ relation: 'foodPrefs', scope: { include: { relation: 'food_pref_to_food_type' }}}]}, function(err, personFound) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }

            cb(null, personFound);
        });

    }

    Person.findEmailAddresses = function(cb) {
        Person.find(function(err, peopleFound) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }
            cb(null, peopleFound);
        });
    }

    Person.remoteMethod(
        'getPrefs', {
            http: {path: '/:personId/getPrefs', verb: 'get'},
            accepts: [{arg: 'personId', type: 'number'}],
            returns: {arg: 'type', type: 'object'},
            description: ['a person object']
        },
        'findEmailAddresses', {
            http: {path: '/:Person', verb: 'get'},
            returns: [{arg: 'email', type: 'object'}],
            description: ['all emails']
        }
    );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To create `more than one` remote method in a single model
2. To create a method called `findEmailAddresses` and have it `return all the emails for all users`.

   ```
   module.exports = function(Person) {
   Person.getPrefs = function(personId, cb) {
       Person.findById(personId, {
           include: [{
               relation: 'foodPrefs',
               scope: {
                   include: {
                       relation: 'food_pref_to_food_type'
                   }
               }
           }]
       }, function(err, personFound) {
           if (err) {
               return cb(err);
           }

           cb(null, personFound);
       });

   }

   Person.findEmailAddresses = function(cb) {
       Person.find(function(err, peopleFound) {
           if (err) {
               return cb(err);
           }
           cb(null, peopleFound);
       });
   }

   Person.remoteMethod(
       'getPrefs', {
           http: {
               path: '/:personId/getPrefs',
               verb: 'get'
           },
           accepts: [{
               arg: 'personId',
               type: 'number'
           }],
           returns: {
               arg: 'type',
               type: 'object'
           },
           description: ['a person object']
       }
   );

   //Now registering the method for returning all the email address of users.
   Person.remoteMethod(
       'findEmailAddresses', {
           http: {
               path: '/:Person',
               verb: 'get'
           },
           returns: {
               arg: 'email',
               type: 'array'
           },
           description: ['all emails']
       }
   );
   }
   ```

> models/person.json

```
 ....
 ....

 "acls": [

    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "getPrefs"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "findEmailAddresses"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: This really looked like it would work, for some reason it's still not showing up in the list of methods in the explorer.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle I have edited the answer. Now it will show in the explorer. You need to set the `ACL` property.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that didn't seem to do the trick either. I thought that might be it too. Weird.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle I am sorry.. the right syntax  should be  `returns: { arg: 'email', type: 'array' }` and not `returns: [{ arg: 'email', type: 'array' }]`

Comment: Could it also be the path? Maybe it's the path. When I changed the path to /Person/findEmailAddresses it finally appeared in explorer but it isn't working properly so we're at least a little further along.

Comment: yeah..may be I think I haven't checked it but please try by providing first argument of `Person`  to your `remoteMethod` since your path is not dynamic here.

Comment: Yeah taking off the brackets worked, that seems to be getting us somewhere finally. Now to get it to show only e-mails. Thanks man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95613/discussion-between-robins-gupta-and-nathan-mckaskle).

Comment: I got it all working:  `path: '/findEmailAddresses'` and `Person.find( { fields: { email: true } } , function(err, peopleFound) ... ` You can edit that into your answer for future people to be more accurate.